# Suggestions to a better preamble for creating a handbook

Tags: best-practices, geometry

The following is the preamble I was given to work with to create a student handbook. I believe there are a few things that are not right. The document compiles well but I am looking for suggestions of improvement.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[text={6in,7.25in},centering,papersize={7in,8.5in},top=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.75in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.4in}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}    
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

First of all, why the `report` class? Is it the best? And well with the geometry, they are trying to maximize the use of the paper size indicated (This, I suppose, remains unchanged.) Of course there is also the `oddsidemargin` and `evensidemargin` issue. Note that I have removed all unnecessary packages and text just to focus on the geometry, class and implementation.

PS: I am not good with the topic of geometry and how its best implemented.

Comment: I think one of the best practice is to avoid using `\setlength` anymore if you load `geometry` because any setting can be done via key-value pairs defined in `geometry`.

Comment: @Pleasedon'ttouch True but how can implement it in the current state of the predefined parameters?

Comment: @Mico Invaluable observations and remarks. There are still a few things in geometry that I cannot get right in my head. If you notice, the odd and even side margin parameters are set so that it allows for binding when the handbook is printed. I suppose there are keyvalues for these, right? If so, how can these be added. Its true about the centering that you mentioned and its being used redundantly.

Comment: @azetina - I've gathered my comments into a standalone answer.

Comment: Don't set `\parindent` to zero; why should five centuries of good typography be ignored? Don't set `\oddsidemargin` and `\evensidemargin`; your aim is probably to leave some offset for the binding, which the `bindingoffset` option for `geometry` is for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are several comments/suggestions. Obviously they cannot be (and are not meant to be) exhaustive.

- If the `\parindent` parameter must be set to zero, it's imperative to set the `\parskip` parameter to some nonzero (positive) value. If you don't adjust `\parskip` as well, there are going to be many cases where it's not clear if a paragraph break has occurred or not.

  Rather than fiddle with the `\parindent` and `\parskip` length parameters directly, I believe it's preferable to load the [parskip](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/parskip/) package, in part because it also adjusts the skips between list items.
- It would seem to be a bit misguided to use the `centering` option when loading the `geometry` package and then set `\evensidemargin` and `\oddsidemargin` to nonzero values. Choosing appropriate binding offsets is obviously very important for the overall look of a document. If it's necessary to adjust the binding offsets, I think it's preferable to do so via options passed to the geometry package rather than via direct manipulation of the low-level TeX parameters `\evensidemargin` and `\oddsidemargin`. The geometry package provides the option `bindingoffset={...}` for this purpose.

  If you do retain the direct approach to manipulating the values of `\evensidemargin` and `\oddsidemargin`, I can't help but think that their current values may be "backwards": the left-hand edge of the text block on an odd-numbered (verso) page is going to be close to the the booklet's binding, and setting `\oddsidemargin` to a *negative* value brings the left hand of the text block perilously close to the binding. Check if these values should maybe be reversed.

  BTW, since it looks like you're using the report document class with the twoside option, there's probably already a binding offset built in to the position of odd-numbered (recto) and even-numbered (verso) pages. For much more on the huge subject of document design, I suggest you take a look at [A Few Notes on Book Design](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/memdesign) by Peter Wilson. This document to be a part of the user guide of the `memoir` package but is now available as a separate, standalone document.
- You may also want to provide the instruction `\raggedbottom`. Even, i.e., uniform spacing between paragraphs may be more important for a student handbook than is having the bottom edges of all pages line up nicely.
- The width of the text block seems a bit excessive. That, or the page margins are too narrow... Either way, the wide text block makes it unnecessarily hard to read and absorb the information that's going to be provided in the student handbook.

  If you must use narrow page margins, consider creating a two-column document. This is most easily done by setting the option `twocolumn` when executing `\documentclass`.
- Must you use Times New Roman? It's a rather impersonal and cold font. While that's just fine for many documents, the use of Times Roman for a student handbook may unintentionally convey the impression that the document is cold and impersonal, which may discourage at least some students from actually bothering to read the document. To other readers, Times Roman may signal "boring!!" -- again reducing the chances that the document will actually get read.

  I don't know which fonts and font packages you have access too, but I'd try an "oldstyle" or "Garalde" font. Give the package `ebgaramond` a try and see if you like the result. A caveat: The `EB Garamond` font family doesn't provide a **bold** face font; it does, to be sure, provide an *italics* font.
- Especially if you use the `twocolumn` document class option, you'll have a lot of paragraphs that contain column and page breaks. To reduce the frequency of typographic widows and orphans (called "clubs" in TeX lingo), you may want to set

  ```
  \widowpenalty10000
  \clubpenalty10000
  ```

Here, then, is my suggestion for the bare-minimum preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,twocolumn]{report}
\usepackage[text={6in,7.25in},papersize={7in,8.5in}]{geometry}
%%\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath} % Times (New) Roman clone
\usepackage{ebgaramond} %% see if you like this font
\usepackage{parskip} % zero parident, nonzero parskip
\raggedbottom        % uniform spacing between parapraphs
\widowpenalty10000
\clubpenalty10000
```

Comment: Wow. I surely learned a lot form your remarks. There are several things I still need to master, i.e., choice of package use and of course there proper implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Please, avoid setting `\parindent` to zero: Five centuries of typography back the choice of indentation for denoting the start of a new paragraph.

I'd use `book`, that has more features than `report`. Don't set `\oddsidemargin` and `\evensidemargin` after using `geometry`: if your aim is to add some space for the binding, then `bindingoffset` is the option you're looking for.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openany]{book}

\usepackage[
  text={6in,7.25in},
  centering,
  papersize={7in,8.5in},
  top=0.5in,
  heightrounded,
  bindingoffset=0.2in,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I should remark that lines are too long and margins too narrow.

Comment: @Pleasedon'ttouch Did you see my final comment?

Comment: Yes. I have read it.